# Exception coming while running JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I am getting this exception while running any JSP on my tomcat5.5 server.Do I need to add any JAR ??? Please Help.

StackTrace:

```
DEBUG http-8181-Processor25 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader -   Loading class from parent
FATAL http-8181-Processor25 org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl - Exception initializing page context

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.appendCookieValue(Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;IZZ)V
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.addCookieInternal(Response.java:970)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2285)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2031)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:832)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:843)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl._initialize(PageContextImpl.java:136)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.initialize(PageContextImpl.java:113)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalGetPageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:105)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.getPageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:62)
    at org.apache.jsp.banner_jsp._jspService(banner_jsp.java:33)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:875)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
DEBUG http-8181-Processor25 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader - loadClass(javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext, false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have `tomcat-coyote.jar` in `$CATALINA_BASE/shared/lib/` folder. If exist somehow its not being loaded to classpath while starting server. Check you have this line in conf/catalina.properties

```
server.loader=${catalina.home}/server/classes,${catalina.home}/server/lib/*.jar
```

If yes then may be you need to update. What enviornment you are using.

Comment: LOGS :  DEBUG main org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext - Compilation classpath initialized: /D:/Soft/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/server/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar ( i can see tomcat-coyote.jar in the classpath along with other jars )

Comment: Okes...Let me check...Using tomcat5.5.27 on windows...I am using very basic JSP.Does this means that we can not run JSP's on tomcat 5.5.27

Comment: no you definitely can run jsp on tomcat... I doubt that jars in lib are not compatible. Try installing later versions. Maybe they had bug in that release. Now they have tomcat 7. Or you can go with tomcat 5.5.33

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is more of the jar versions you are using or jars you are in your class path. It is trying to point to in correct class version due to which the required method is unavailable. Which all jars are already set in your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing any jars. Otherwise you would have got `ClassNotFound exception`. The `NoSuchMethodError` indicates that the jars are not compatible. Did you by any chance change(or copy from different location) the jar files in /lib, espcially `jasper*.jar, tomcat-coyote`?