# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am getting this exception on my Tomcat 7 server startup. I am using eclipse IDE. I have no clue why this exception is coming. My application was working fine a while ago. I did not make any changes in my build path also.This is the stack trace.

```
    Feb 16, 2015 10:06:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener lifecycleEvent
    WARNING: Couldn't initialize Jasper
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener.lifecycleEvent(JasperListener.java:63)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)

    Feb 16, 2015 10:06:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Feb 16, 2015 10:06:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Feb 16, 2015 10:06:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 1452 ms
    Feb 16, 2015 10:06:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Feb 16, 2015 10:06:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
    Feb 16, 2015 10:06:40 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
    INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [590] milliseconds.
    Feb 16, 2015 10:06:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Marking servlet jsp as unavailable
    Feb 16, 2015 10:06:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
    SEVERE: Servlet  threw load() exception
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:506)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:488)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1148)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5518)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Feb 16, 2015 10:06:40 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
    INFO: validateJarFile(D:\Workspaces\Inventory\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\rms\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
    Feb 16, 2015 10:06:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Marking servlet jsp as unavailable
    Feb 16, 2015 10:06:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
    SEVERE: Servlet /rms threw load() exception
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:506)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:488)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1148)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5518)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I saw other questions where it was suggested that the issue could be the JRE runtime pointing to the jdk instead of jre. But I can see thats not the case for me.

Comment: It says javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar is not loaded. Take a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21950908/jar-file-failed-to-load-in-tomcat-webapps)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238420/exception-coming-while-running-jsp